# How to get or set x-ms-client-request-id or x-ms-request-id in Azure Storage SDK for Python

Tags: python, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Does anyone know how to get or set x-ms-client-request-id (client request id) or x-ms-request-id (request id) in Azure Storage SDK for Python?

When executing a request to Storage by SDK, x-ms-client-request-id and x-ms-request-id are appended to the header. Also these are logged if Storage Analytics is turned on. I'd like to confirm whether requests are coming to Storage correctly by using x-ms-client-request-id or x-ms-request-id.
I'm using these methods.

```
block_blob_service.put_block(container_name, blob_name, blob_stream, block_id)
block_blob_service.put_block_list(container_name, blob_name, block_ids)
```

I searched on internet, but I couldn't find the sample code.

If C#, I know we can get x-ms-client-request-id in OperationContext attribute.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfromfileasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlockBlob_UploadFromFileAsync_System_String_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_AccessCondition_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_System_IProgress_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Core_Util_StorageProgress__System_Threading_CancellationToken_

Comment: Hi,any progress now?

Answer (score 0):

I searched the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/19d845d58551bd36a04c46628dc42089ee269362/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/blockblobservice.py) for function : `block_blob_service.put_block_list` but I did't find any parameters related to `x-ms-request-id`.

```
def _put_block_list(
        self, container_name, blob_name, block_list, content_settings=None,
        metadata=None, validate_content=False, lease_id=None, if_modified_since=None,
        if_unmodified_since=None, if_match=None, if_none_match=None,
        timeout=None, encryption_data=None):
    '''
    See put_block_list for more details. This helper method
    allows for encryption or other such special behavior because
    it is safely handled by the library. These behaviors are
    prohibited in the public version of this function.
    :param str encryption_data:
        A JSON formatted string containing the encryption metadata generated for this 
        blob if it was encrypted all at once upon upload. This should only be passed
        in by internal methods.
    '''

    _validate_not_none('container_name', container_name)
    _validate_not_none('blob_name', blob_name)
    _validate_not_none('block_list', block_list)
    request = HTTPRequest()
    request.method = 'PUT'
    request.host_locations = self._get_host_locations()
    request.path = _get_path(container_name, blob_name)
    request.query = {
        'comp': 'blocklist',
        'timeout': _int_to_str(timeout),
    }
    request.headers = {
        'x-ms-lease-id': _to_str(lease_id),
        'If-Modified-Since': _datetime_to_utc_string(if_modified_since),
        'If-Unmodified-Since': _datetime_to_utc_string(if_unmodified_since),
        'If-Match': _to_str(if_match),
        'If-None-Match': _to_str(if_none_match),
    }
    _add_metadata_headers(metadata, request)
    if content_settings is not None:
        request.headers.update(content_settings._to_headers())
    request.body = _get_request_body(
        _convert_block_list_to_xml(block_list))

    if validate_content:
        computed_md5 = _get_content_md5(request.body)
        request.headers['Content-MD5'] = _to_str(computed_md5)

    if encryption_data is not None:
        request.headers['x-ms-meta-encryptiondata'] = encryption_data

    return self._perform_request(request, _parse_base_properties)
```

According to the [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list) , `x-ms-client-request-id` is optional. So i suggest you adopt workaround that you could add this parameter to above function.

```
if request_client_id is not None:
        request.headers['x-ms-client-request-id'] = _to_str(request_client_id)
```